# Link without referer

Tags: php, hyperlink, referrer

How can I make it so when the site visitor of mysite.com clicks a link, like http://google.com, the referrer page is not sent to the target website ?

Is this possible with PHP ?

Basically I want the linked site to not be aware where the visitor came from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible, as the HTTP referrer information is sent by the browser. You can install browser plugins to prevent sending referrers, but not directly with PHP.

**Update**: I just found this

> If a website is accessed from a HTTP Secure (HTTPS) connection and a link points to anywhere except another secure location, then the referrer field is not sent.
>   The upcoming standard HTML5 will support the attribute/value rel = "noreferrer" in order to instruct the user agent not to send a referrer.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer#Referrer_hiding

Answer (score 2):

The referer is set by the browser, not the server, so broadly speaking, you can't really control this.

You may be able to find ways to mask mysite.com by redirecting the user through an intermediary site to google.com.  I wouldn't recommend this, though.

Answer (score 1):

No. Not possible. The client (broswer) is responsible for that HTTP header. A browser might even choose to not (ever) send it. (I'm not sure about the exact protocols/specifications of when to send it.)

**edit**
There might be a trick. (But I don't know it.) Maybe some JavaScript or header cancelling image or something nasty.